# Does public inheritance allow to override the base classes member accessors?

Tags: c++, inheritance, public, protected

I read in a code sample something strange. There is a base class and a derived class. Derived class is derived from the base class with public inheritance.

```
class baseClass
{
public:
    void foo();
}

class derivedClass : public baseClass
{
protected:
    void foo();
}
```

The derived class also overrides the accessor of the method `foo()`. `foo()` is `public` in `baseClass` and `protected` in `derivedClass`. It builds and works, but I don't see why anyone would do this and also to which extent this is allowed. For instance, protected narrows the access, so it is allowed but you can't override a base class protected method with public? I don't know.

Comment: It doesn't override, it hides.

Comment: Sorry, I apparently used a wrong term. Can you please explain the difference?

Comment: In `derivedClass` a new `foo()` is defined, and the `foo()` of the base class is hided, i.e. can't be called from the derived class. The new `foo()` in `derivedClass` has nothing to do with the base class's one, i.e. has nothing to do with the access of the base class member `foo()`.

Comment: And only virtual member function could be overrided.

Answer (score 3):

What you wrote is a little tricky. The result of your code won't be what you expect. If you create and use `derivedClass` instance you just can't call `foo()` cause it's protected:

```
derivedClass object;
object.foo(); // Compilation error. Cannot access.
```

But if you create a pointer to a `derivedClass` class object and calls the `foo()` function it will call `baseClass`'s `foo()` not `derivedClass`'s `foo()` cause it's not a virtual a function in the base class.

```
baseClass* object = new derivedClass;
object->foo(); // This will call baseClass::foo();
```

This is the case when you hide the function. If you add the `virtual` keyword to `foo()` then `derivedClass`'s `foo()` will be called.

```
class baseClass
{
public:
    virtual void foo();
}

class derivedClass : public baseClass
{
protected:
    virtual void foo() override;
}
```

Usage:

```
baseClass* object = new derivedClass;
object->foo(); // This will call derivedClass::foo();
```

Comment: Note the use of the C++11 keyword `override` here. It will actually generate an error message if, by accident, you're *hiding* instead of *overriding* a base class function. (This is what it was introduced for.)

Answer (score 1):

Virtual functions can be overridden.   That is one of the points of virtual functions.

In your example, however, `derivedClass::foo()` hides `baseClass::foo()`.  It does not override it.

This can be demonstrated as follows

```
//  your class definitions here
int main()
{
     baseClass b;
     derivedClass c;
     baseClass *pb = &b;
     baseClass *pc = &c;

     b.foo();     // will call baseClass::foo()
     pb->foo();   // will also call baseClass::foo()
     pc->foo();   // will also call baseClass::foo()  (not derivedClass::foo() which would be the case if baseClass::foo() was virtual)

     c.foo();     //  will attempt to call derivedClass::foo(), which the compiler will reject since it is protected                      
}
```

The statement `c.foo()` will compile if `derivedClass::foo()` was `public`, and will call `derivedClass::foo()`.   Depending on compiler and compiler settings, the compiler may issue a warning about `baseClass::foo()` being hidden.